# Custom Stack Allocator, override Delete 

Tags: c++, stack, new-operator, delete-operator

I want to create a global stack in my application, and to place certain objects on to this stack. These objects are not of a fixed size.

I currently have;

```
static char contextStack[CONTEXT_MAX_SIZE];
static char *top = &contextStack[0];
```

and I override the `new` operator of a base class which is inherited

```
static void *operator new(size_t size) {
  void *Result;
  Result = top;
  top = top + size;
  return Result;
};
```

The problem is how would I implement the `delete` operator to pop it off the stack? It doesn't tell me how big the item was? Do I have to store the size of each entry in an array?

(p.s) The last one created is always the first to be deleted. And conforms to a stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different options to handle the memory in this case. If you are returning memory in increasing order (which seems to be the case), you do not need to remember the size. The last memory block allocated will be from *allocated pointer* to *top*, and you don't even need to perform the arithmetic, as setting top to be the pointer passed to `delete` will suffice.

If you were allocating memory in descending order (as is common in a stack) you can store the size in the stack itself. Perform the pointer arithmetic to obtain the new `Result` (`top - requested_size`), then decrement `sizeof(int)`, store the size there and set the `top` pointer to be that pointer.

You should be aware of alignment restrictions in your platform, and even if the platform allows unaligned access to all data types, you might want to still align the data for performance (and thread-safety) reasons.

Comment: doh! ofcourse the p from delete operator = top! Is there any disadvantage to ascending stacks? Would alignment be simply making sure that contextStack starts at a nice address and in the new operator the Result is padded forward?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to store the size of each entry in an array?

You can use a separate storage area, or you could use the strategy that `malloc` implementations often follow: they store the size in a known location in front of the pointer that they return to you. When you call `free`, they check the location immediately prior to the pointer that you pass in, grab the size from there, and proceed with deallocation.

In your case, you could push the size of the chunk right after the chunk itself. When it's time to pop the stack, pop the size first, and then pop the data chunk.

One thing that you need to be aware of when working with your stack is data alignment: depending on an architecture, storing multibyte types at odd offsets (offsets indivisible by four, eight, etc.) may cause performance degradation or bus errors. You need to check your platform specifics to see if you need to introduce extra "padding" between consecutive elements pushed onto your stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a template class in order to create a stack , you don't need to know the size of each item , it's much more easy .

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from my experience with Assembly when dealing with the stack: when code wants to pop something off the stack, that code is responsible for knowing how large that something is or is expected to be. The stack is just a huge chunk of data in a row, and you can technically take off however large a piece you want, as long as there is that much there.

So your code needs to know how big the object is ahead of time (information you don't seem to have). You could, of course, implement your "stack" in any number of other ways, including your suggestion of storing sizes in an array. Doing so further complicates the simplicity of having a stack, but it may be necessary in your implementation.